# Pulling a section of a string between two characters in SQL, and the section of the string around the extracted section

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that includes names and allows for a "nickname" for each name in parenthesis.

| PersonName |
| --- |
| John (Johnny) Hendricks |
| Zekeraya (Zeke) Smith |
| Ajamain Sterling (Aljo) |
| Beth ()) Jackson |

I need to extract the Nickname, and return a column of nicknames and a column of full names (Full string without the nickname portion in parenthesis). I also need a condition for the nickname to be null if no nickname exists, and so that the nickname only returns letters. So far I have been able to figure out how to get the nickname out using Substring, but I can't figure out how to create a separate column for just the name.

```
Select SUBSTRING(PersonName, CHARINDEX('(', PersonName) +1,(((LEN(PersonName))-CHARINDEX(')',REVERSE(PersonName)))-CHARINDEX('(',PersonName)))
```

as NickName
from dbo.Person

Any help would be appreciated. I'm using MS SQL Server 2019. I'm pretty new at this, as you can tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your existing `substring`, one simple way is to use `apply`.

Assuming your last row is an example of a nickname that should be NULL, you can use an *inline if* to check its length - presumably a nickname must be longer than 1 character? Adjust this logic as required.

```
select PersonName, Iif(Len(nn)<2,null,nn) NickName, Trim(Replace(Replace(personName, Concat('(',nn,')') ,''),'  ','')) FullName
from Person
cross apply (values(SUBSTRING(PersonName, CHARINDEX('(', PersonName) +1,(((LEN(PersonName))-CHARINDEX(')',REVERSE(PersonName)))-CHARINDEX('(',PersonName))) ))c(nn)
```

Comment: So this partially works, but it doesn't remove the nickname in the FullName column for the case where the NickName comes at the end of the full name. It also doesn't return a Null for the Nickname field when there is no nickname or when the Parenthesis only have special characters inside. Any ideas there? Appreciate the assistance!

Comment: @fender120 I have made a minor edit above, can you check now and advise if it meets your criteria?

Comment: Just for clarity check the results with [this Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=979b630465eccb59113238f6319345e6)

Comment: This does work for all of the conditions I specified, so thank you! Could you please tell me what the edit would be for this to include names with the nickname at the beginning? EX: (Laurie) Lauren Murphy

Comment: That does require a slightly less elegant method to deal with the spaces, but have again modified.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will deal correctly with missing parenthesis or empty strings.

Note how the first `CROSS APPLY` feeds into the next

```
SELECT
  PersonName,
  NULLIF(NickName, ''),
  FullName = ISNULL(REPLACE(personName, ' (' + NickName + ')', ''), PersonName)
FROM t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(
  NULLIF(CHARINDEX('(', PersonName), 0))
) v1(opening)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(
  SUBSTRING(
    PersonName,
    v1.opening + 1,
    NULLIF(CHARINDEX(')', PersonName, v1.opening), 0) - v1.opening - 1
   )
)) v2(NickName);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=a9dd7cfbc3fd2f1b42a1a5422da8a5ad)